# Validation rules in cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have field "type" that need to be unique and rule for the field will be "active" == 1.

```
$validator
        ->notEmpty('type')
        ->add('type', [
            'unique' => [
               'rule' => ['validateUnique', ['scope' => ['aktivan' => '1']]],
               'provider' => 'table', 
               'message' => 'Not unique']
        ]);
```

I try this but doesn't work. I am new to Cakephp and I need help with this.

Comment: active = 1 , why you are not setting this value as a default value in database ?

Comment: what do you think unique means?